# Android cannot get boolean value from bundle

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-bundle, gcmlistenerservice

In my GcmListenerService I am getting this bundle data:

```
Bundle[{gcm.notification.e=1, gcm.notification.title=SomeApp, proceed=true, gcm.notification.body=Some text, message=Some message, collapse_key=example.com.SomeApp}]
```

I am can get the **message** by

```
bundle.getString("message");
```

But i cannot get the **proceed** boolean value int the bundle data.
I used:

```
bundle.getBoolean("proceed",false);
```

this is always giving false, even when the value is **true** in the bundle data.
It is so simple, i don't know what i am missing.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `bundle.getString("proceed");` to see if it is stored as a `String`?

Comment: No, i used getBoolean as it has a default value. i gues i will have to check with getString and check for null value. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: it was accidentally sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the value of `proceed` looks to be a `boolean` it is likely stored in the `Bundle` as a `String` and that is why you cannot get the value of it using `bundle.getBoolean()`.

You should use `bundle.getString("proceed");` instead.

You can parse the `String` into a `boolean` if you need to.

```
boolean proceed = Boolean.parseBoolean(bundle.getString("proceed", "false"));
```

Comment: thanks, it is working now. But i was sending it as a boolean to gcm server by php. so i thought it would remain boolean.

Comment: I can see the confusion there. I tried finding somewhere in the documentation whether or not it said all values are sent as Strings but didn't find much. The `onMessageReceived` says the `Bundle` is `message data as String key/value pairs`. Not sure if that means always `String` for both key and value.